# microsoft graph cant get refresh token using refresh token

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, microsoft-graph-api

The first time I was able to get both access token and refresh token,
Then when I use the refresh token to refresh it only gave me back access token and doesn't give me back the refresh token too, I want to get both the refresh token and access token,

```
request_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

scope_list = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite"]
scope = "%20".join(scope_list)

# redirect_uri = f"{settings.FRONTEND_BASE_URL}/microsoft/login"
redirect_uri = (
    f"https://someuri.com/login"
)

refresh_token = user.profile.calendar_settings.outlook_refresh_token

payload = {
    "client_id": "",
    "scope": scope,
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    "client_secret": "",
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token": refresh_token,
}

response = requests.post(url=request_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the scope to this

```
scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure your call includes following parameters in payload

> ```
> grant_type:refresh_token
> client_id:"your_client_id_comes_here"
> client_secret:"your_client_secret_comes_here"
> response_type:token
> refresh_token:"old_refres_token_comes_here"
> ```

For more details please refer below screenshot

[Postman request to get new access token with refresh token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6lYm.png)